# Logitech Script, Press and hold key until releas

Tags: lua, scripting, logitech, logitech-gaming-software

Is it possible to make Logitech scripts targets letters?

For example > F

Using mouse button `5` if I wanted this logitech script to press hold `F` key until release of mouse button `5` how would I do that?

```
function OnEvent(event, arg)

if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_RELEASED" and arg == 5 then

PressAndReleaseMouseButton(5);

end
```

Comment: Welcome to SO- please see - How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example
When asking a question, people will be better able to provide help if you provide code that they can easily understand and use to reproduce the problem. This is called creating a minimal, reproducible example (reprex), a minimal, complete and verifiable example (mcve), or a minimal, workable example (mwe). - https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function OnEvent(event, arg)
   if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 5 then
      PressKey("F")
   end
   if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_RELEASED" and arg == 5 then
      ReleaseKey("F")
   end
end
```

But you can do the same without writing the script.
Just bind the key `F` to mouse button 5 by simple drag-and-drop.

Comment: The code you provided does press it however in the game I'm using it doesn't repress/let go like the above code is working

Comment: @damian - In your original code replace `PressMouseButton(1);` with `PressKey("G")` and `ReleaseMouseButton(1);` with `ReleaseKey("G")`.